# SQL Server 2008 - Multiple Cascading FK's - Do i need a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes, relationships

I have a 1..* relationship between **User** and **Post**. (one user has many posts)

**Post** has a FK called "UserId", which maps to the "UserId" field on **User** table.

I tried to set this FK as Cascade UPDATE/DELETE, but i get this error:

> 'Users' table saved successfully
>   'Posts' table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'FK_Posts_Users'.
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Posts_Users' on table 'Posts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I have a table called **PostHelpful.** One Post has many Helpful's.

Helpful has a cascading FK to User (so when a User is deleted, their Helpful's are also deleted).

But i think this is the cause of complaint for "multiple cascade paths".

Because if i delete a User (currently), it will delete their helpfuls. But im trying to add a cacade to Post also, do it would delete the Post, then try and delete the Helpful's for that Post (as Helpful also has a cascading FK to Post). In that scenario, which cascading FK would SQL choose?

Here is the database diagram of the three tables in question:

[image]

As you can see, "PostHelpful" is a child to both "Post" and "User" (has FK's to both).

So i can't make both keys cascading? Do i need a trigger on "Users" (AFTER DELETE) to manually delete the helpfuls (and other tables referencing User).

Comment: You have found the problem and how to fix it. Remove the cascade delete between User and PostHelpful, add a trigger to User that `on delete` delete in PostHelpful. Then you should be able to add the cascade delete between User and Post.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson - really? i mean it would work, but i was hoping it was the wrong way to do things. Triggers should not enforce referential integrity.

Comment: Hm. Never considered cascade delete as a part of referential integrity constraint. More like a convenient way to handle delete. I would probably not use trigger or cascade delete. I would write a stored procedure that delete in the correct order.

Comment: My bad, not referential integrity - that was a bad choice of words. I mean that deleting relationships should be handled by the FK. E.g when a parent is deleted, any children are automatically deleted. This is not really a trigger's job, or a stored procedure for that matter. I'm using an ORM here (EF), so the parent is deleted by code, so i can't use stored procs. It's either setup the correct cascading FK's, or use a trigger.

Comment: @marc_s - I'd love to read your thoughts, about this problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a matter of which path will SQL Server choose, it does not allow it so that it won't wind up in a compromising position. When we ran into this situation, we had to resort to a trigger.

1) As the error message stated, change the **Users_PostHelpfuls** FK to **ON DELETE NO ACTION**.

2) Add an **INSTEAD OF DELETE** trigger to Users:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Users_IO_Delete 
ON dbo.Users
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN;
    DELETE FROM dbo.PostHelpfuls WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM deleted);

    DELETE FROM dbo.Users WHERE UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM deleted);
END;
```

Now, the FK will still enforce DRI, but the trigger is cascading the delete rather than the FK constraint.

You could replace **PostHelpfuls** with **Posts** in the above steps. But when doing this it's best to use the trigger to remove the less independent entity's records. In other words, it's more likely that **Posts** are related to tables beside **Users** and **PostHelpfuls** than **PostHelpfuls** is related to tables beside **Users** and **Posts**.

Comment: Okay, this is what i figured. So i now have three people saying the same thing. Damn, okay - cheers.