# Creating SQL constraint with possible circular dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, circular-dependency

I've the following table structure (fictive, to demonstarate):

```
ArticlePrice
------------
Id (int, identity)
Price (float)

SpecialArticlePrice
-------------------
Id (int, identity)
ArticlePriceId (int, FK to AriclePrice.Id)
SpecialPrice (float)
```

Between these to tables is a delete constraint.

```
Foo
-----
Id (int, identity)
ArticlePriceId (int, NULL, FKto ArticlePrice.Id)
SpecialArticlePriceId (int, NULL, FK to SpecialArticlePrice.Id)
Price (int)
```

I want to set a delete constraint to both FKs in case of either the ArticelPrice or SpecialArticlePrice will be deleted, the Foo record should also be deleted.
The only contract (on developer site) is, that a record of Foo will only hold one FK relationship.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (ArticlePrice, SpecialArticlePrice, Price) VALUES (13, NULL, 20.0) 
INSERT INTO Foo (ArticlePrice, SpecialArticlePrice, Price) VALUES (NULL, 3, 134.25)
```

How can I solve this scenario?

Thank you very much.
Kind regards,
Danny

Comment: I doubt you have cyclic dependency.I would suggest that you post the ddl of tables.Insert some data in these tables and then say delete one row from articleprice table and show what output you expect for other tables. Then delete one row from specialarticleprice  and specify what you expect the output of other two tables.Then people will be able to help much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Triggers along with stored proc.
[SQL Server 2008 - Multiple Cascading FK's - Do i need a trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100525/sql-server-2008-multiple-cascading-fks-do-i-need-a-trigger)

Many Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 2):

You need to create `DELETE TRIGGERS` on your ArticlePrice and SpecialArticlePrice tables.

```
create trigger trgArticlePriceDelete on ArticlePrice for delete
as
begin
delete foo 
from foo
        inner join deleted on foo.ArticlePriceID = deleted.ID
end
go

create trigger trgSpecialArticlePriceDelete on SpecialArticlePrice for delete
as
begin
    delete foo 
    from
        foo
        inner join deleted on foo.SpecialArticlePriceID = deleted.ID
end
go
```

Also, you shouldn't store your prices as floats. Use `money` or a `decimal` type

Comment: Doesn't work. The FKs will be checked before any trigger action can excecute. The solution is using triggers of the type INSTEAD OF DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got that what you really want to achieve BUT:

If you design the Foo-Table in SSMS you have to insert the Foreign Keys. 
Then you'll need to set the "Insert and Update Specification" of the Foreign Key of the SpecialPrice-Table and ArticlePrice-Table (the Relationship to the Table Foo) --> Just set the Delete Rule to **Cascade**.

As a result, everytime you delete an ArticlePrice or a SpecialArticlePrice the rows referencing those items should be deleted as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting this rule is not allowed because of a circular dependency ;) If i delete a ArticlePrice record the rule will delete the SpecialPrice record and the Foo record. After that the database want to delete the Foo record again because there is the second rule between SpecialArticlePrice and Foo... In my scenario there won't be set both FKs at the same time, but the database don't know that. Oracle has something like NOCYCLE I guess.